# Get Object value by string path

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I have this string
`Member.User.Name`

and this instance:

```
Root root = new Root();
root.Member.User.Name = "user name";
```

How do I extract the value from `root` of the member `Member.User.Name`

for example:

```
string res = GetDeepPropertyValue(root, "Member.User.Name");
```

`res` will be "user name"

Thanks

Comment: `.GetProperty()` recursively? Your question is unclear and does not show research effort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
public object GetDeepPropertyValue(object instance, string path){
  var pp = path.Split('.');
  Type t = instance.GetType();
  foreach(var prop in pp){
    PropertyInfo propInfo = t.GetProperty(prop);
    if(propInfo != null){
      instance = propInfo.GetValue(instance, null);
      t = propInfo.PropertyType;
    }else throw new ArgumentException("Properties path is not correct");
  }
  return instance;
}
string res = GetDeepPropertyValue(root, "Member.User.Name").ToString();
```

**NOTE**: We don't need recursive solution for this because the **number of loops** is known beforehand. Using `foreach` would be more efficient if possible. **We use recursion only when the implementation becomes complicated with `for - foreach`**.

Comment: You shouldn't use `propInfo.PropertyType` but `instance.GetType()` as the actual value that the property holds may be derived from the property type.

Comment: @AdiLester it may be right, but the `Properties path` is the path in which all the properties should be defined in the classes, that means using `PropertyType` will be OK.

Comment: What do you mean by "should be defined"? If I have a property `object MyObj { get; set; }` and I assign it a `Person` object, I'd expect this method to give me the person's name for `MyObj.Name` and not throw an exception. At least that's how property paths work in other places like binding in WPF.

Comment: @AdiLester that's not what the OP wants, I mean all the defined classes will show its properties with type declared clearly, based on that we can build the `properties path` and access at runtime. However your idea is very good for achieving the value more dynamically. While using `PropertyInfo` only return value when the `path` can be derived from the classes definitions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to work against dynamic objects...

Comment: It does work however if you make the change @AdiLester mentioned...

Answer (score 4):

Shazam I believe you are looking to access the property using reflection in recursive way

```
public static object GetDeepPropertyValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        if (propName.Contains('.'))
        {
            string[] Split = propName.Split('.');
            string RemainingProperty = propName.Substring(propName.IndexOf('.') + 1);
            return GetDeepPropertyValue(src.GetType().GetProperty(Split[0]).GetValue(src, null), RemainingProperty);
        }
        else
            return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
    }
```

Don't forget to add validation checks if needed.